# GCC 4.6 and missing variadic-templates expansions

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, variadic-templates

I'm using this code to create multiple functions wrappers using variadic templates:

```
// Compile with g++ -std=c++0x $(pkg-config sigc++-2.0 --cflags --libs) test.cpp -o test
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <sigc++/sigc++.h>

template <typename R, typename G, typename... Ts>
class FuncWrapper
{
public:
  FuncWrapper(G object, std::string const& name, sigc::slot<R, Ts...> function) {};
};

int main()
{
  FuncWrapper<void, int, int, bool, char> tst(0, "test", [] (int a, bool b, char c) {});

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code correctly compiles with clang++, but not with g++ due to the known issue:

> test.cpp:9:73: sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand ‘Ts ...’ into a
>   fixed-length argument list

I know that gcc-4.7 should handle this correctly, but I can't upgrade for now... So I'd like to have a workaround to make `Ts...` to unpack correctly. I've tested what suggested here in questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539716/implementing-meta-function-zip-in-c11), but they don't seem to solve the issue here.

Comment: I've once seen this same error when I actually tried to misuse variadic templates, and upgrading didn't help (fixing the code did). Just mentioning

Comment: BTW why sigc++ not std::function?

Comment: @Kos I'm working on a framework where we use sigc::slot as base...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can workaround the bug with:

```
template<template <typename...> class T, typename... Args>
struct Join
{ typedef T<Args...> type; };
```

then replace `sigc::slot<R, Ts...>` with `typename Join<sigc::slot, R, Ts...>::type`

(Thanks to Chris Jefferson's suggestion on the [GCC bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35722#c12))