# Variadic Template, no matching function call

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm writing an implementation of `zip`, but I've ran into a bit of a problem.  Here's a minimal test case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename... Types>
Container<std::tuple<Types...>> zip(Container<Types> const&... args) {
  unsigned len = commonLength(args...);
  Container<std::tuple<Types...>> res;
  std::tuple<Types...> item;

  for (unsigned i=0; i<len; i++) {
    item = getTupleFrom(i, args...);
    res.push_back(item);
  }

  return res;
}

template <class ContainerA, class... Containers>
unsigned commonLength(ContainerA first, Containers... rest, unsigned len=std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()) {
  unsigned firstLen = first.size();
  if (len > firstLen) {
    len = firstLen;
  }
  return commonLength(rest..., len);
}

template <class ContainerA>
unsigned commonLength(ContainerA first, unsigned len=std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()) {
  unsigned firstLen = first.size();
  if (len > firstLen) {
    len = firstLen;
  }
  return len;
}

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename TypeA, typename... Types>
std::tuple<TypeA, Types...> getTupleFrom(unsigned index, Container<TypeA> const& first, Container<Types> const&... rest) {
  return std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<TypeA>(first[index]), getTupleFrom(index, rest...));
}

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename TypeA>
std::tuple<TypeA> getTupleFrom(unsigned index, Container<TypeA> const& first) {
  return std::tuple<TypeA>(first[index]);
}

int main() {

  std::deque<int> test1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::deque<std::string> test2 = {"hihi", "jump", "queue"};
  std::deque<float> test3 = {0.2, 8.3, 7, 123, 2.3};
  for (auto i : zip(test1, test2, test3)) {
    std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << std::get<1>(i) << std::get<2>(i) << std::endl;
  }
  //expected output:
  //1hihi0.2
  //2jump8.3
  //3queue7
  return 0;
}
```

When compiling I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘commonLength(const Star::List<int>&, const Star::List<std::basic_string<char> >&, const Star::List<float>&)’
note: candidates are:
note: template<class ContainerA, class ... Containers> unsigned int Star::commonLength(ContainerA, Containers ..., unsigned int)
note: template<class ContainerA> unsigned int Star::commonLength(ContainerA, unsigned int)
```

I'm assuming I'm specifying my template parameters wrong or something like that.  I also attempted to restructure and eliminate that function altogether, but then I get the same error against `getTupleFrom`.

Can anyone explain to me why I'm stupid?  Because I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

template <class ContainerA>
unsigned commonLength(unsigned len, const ContainerA &first) {
  unsigned firstLen = first.size();
  if (len > firstLen) {
    len = firstLen;
  }
  return len;
}


template <class ContainerA, class... Containers>
unsigned commonLength(unsigned len, const ContainerA &first, const Containers&... rest) {
  unsigned firstLen = first.size();
  if (len > firstLen) {
    len = firstLen;
  }
  return commonLength(len, rest...);
}

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename TypeA>
std::tuple<TypeA> getTupleFrom(unsigned index, Container<TypeA> const& first) {
  return std::tuple<TypeA>(first[index]);
}

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename TypeA, typename... Types>
std::tuple<TypeA, Types...> getTupleFrom(unsigned index, Container<TypeA> const& first, Container<Types> const&... rest) {
  return std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<TypeA>(first[index]), getTupleFrom(index, rest...));
}

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename... Types>
Container<std::tuple<Types...>> zip(Container<Types> const&... args) {
  unsigned len = commonLength(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max(), args...);
  Container<std::tuple<Types...>> res;
  std::tuple<Types...> item;

  for (unsigned i=0; i<len; i++) {
    item = getTupleFrom(i, args...);
    res.push_back(item);
  }

  return res;
}

int main() {

  std::deque<int> test1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::deque<std::string> test2 = {"hihi", "jump", "queue"};
  std::deque<float> test3 = {0.2, 8.3, 7, 123, 2.3};
  for (auto i : zip(test1, test2, test3)) {
    std::cout << std::get<0>(i) << std::get<1>(i) << std::get<2>(i) << std::endl;
  }
  //expected output:
  //1hihi0.2
  //2jump8.3
  //3queue7
}
```

It outputs exactly what you expected. The problems were:

- You weren't using `const&` containers in `commonLength`, while `zip`'s arguments where const references.
- The unsigned parameter in `commonLength` coudln't be deduced, so I moved it to the beginning
- You declared/defined functions in the wrong order(A required B, but A was defined before B), so I reordered them.

Apparently clang 3.1 fails to deduce the template arguments in `zip`, but g++ 4.6 gets them fine.

Comment: Haha, wrong order declaration.  Thanks so much for finding that.  I knew it was something stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Picking step by step.

You are missing headers:

```
#include <limits>
```

You have undeclared identifiers:

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename TypeA, typename... Types>
std::tuple<TypeA, Types...> getTupleFrom(unsigned index, Container<TypeA> const& first, Container<Types> const&... rest) {
  return std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<TypeA>(first[index]), getTupleFrom(index, rest...), end);
}
```

where is `end` declared?

You are inconsistent:

```
Container<std::tuple<Types...>> zip(Container<Types> const&... args) {
  unsigned len = commonLength(args...);
  Container<std::tuple<Types...>> res;
```

Is it `Container<std::tuple<Types...>>` or `Container<Types>`? Or is this exactly what you mean? Your code is a bit complex for just a quick review.

Then, you have only versions of `getTupleFrom` for non-zero counts of `Container<TypeA>`,

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename TypeA, typename... Types>
std::tuple<TypeA, Types...> getTupleFrom(unsigned index, Container<TypeA> const& first, Container<Types> const&... rest) {
  return std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<TypeA>(first[index]), getTupleFrom(index, rest...), end);
}

template <template <typename...> class Container, typename TypeA>
std::tuple<TypeA> getTupleFrom(unsigned index, Container<TypeA> const& first) {
  return std::tuple<TypeA>(first[index]);
}
```

which is why there is an error of

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘getTupleFrom(unsigned int&)’
```

which indicates that you somehow reached a point where your argument list is empty (except for the unsigned integer argument). I guess you need to prevent this.

Comment: I'll edit my post.  I hacked this out of a quasi functional piece of code, so I missed a header, the `end` is a relic from the aforementioned attempt to remove the function that's giving the error.  Even with it removed it doesn't fix the issue, but thanks for catching it.

Comment: + a warning "control reaches end of non-void function."

Comment: The most recent edit where you ask about `Container<std::tuple<Types...>>` or `Container<Types>` this is exactly what I mean, this code is a `zip` function much like the python version of the function.  It is intended to take several lists and return a list of tuples.

Comment: @jrok: But I do not see any non-void functions without return statement.

Comment: @phresnel, he was referring to `main` which I edited recently to suppress the warning.

Comment: @phresnel Hey, it's what my compiler said :) I didn't try to visually find it. Edit: it was a side effect of another error.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: I am not sure if it is a good approach to combine X distinct lists of distinct type into a list of X*Y elements, where only Y elements are active and the rest is only default initialized, but still wasting memory.

Comment: @jrok: That's strange. You don't have to have a return statement in main, even though it is always `int`.

Comment: @jrok: I realise that g++ complains about a missing return statement in the first version of `getTupleFrom()`, not `main()`. This is because the return statement isn't correct and thus a follow-up error of previous errors. In C++, always fix from top to bottom :) (edit: yeah, side effect, as you name it :) )