# Array printing in a specific order

Tags: javascript

I have 3 arrays say A, B, C
A has a1,a2,a3 similarly b1,b2,b3 for B and C.

When I print their elements, they come like this

```
return(A)-->a1,a2,a3
return(B)-->b1,b2,b3
return(C)-->c1,c2,c3
```

How could I manipulate these array to another array say D to print something like this

```
return(D)-->
a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3
```

I use javascript .

Comment: Write a custom `sort` function.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a loop for that if they all have the same length like this:

```
var D = [];

for(var i = 0; i<A.length; i++){
  D.push(A[i],B[i],C[i]);
}

return D;
```

Comment: How will it do if he has variable number of elements in each array?

Comment: do you want only the indexes that all arrays have or concat the longer arrays on the end too like a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c3,b3,c3?

Comment: My question was what if A has a1,a2 and B has b1,b2,b3,b4.

Comment: Yep i got that, but do you want to return a1,b1,a2,b2,b3,b4 then or just a1,b1,a2,b2?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called a [zip operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115563/what-is-zip-functional-programming). Javascript does not have *zip* by default. I wrote a small zip function which might work for you, what it expects is that all arrays have the same length. To be a bit more precise, it would want all the arrays to have atleast as many elements as are there in element #1. This essentially does what @Igle's code does, except that it uses a bit different approach and can take any number of arrays.

Note: You might need to do a bit of error checking in below code

```
var zip = function (array) {
   return array.slice(1).reduce(function(prev,cur) {
       return prev.map(function(x,i){
           return x.concat(cur[i]);
       });
   }, array[0].map(function(x){return [x];}));
}

zip ([ ['a1','a2','a3'] ,  ['b1','b2','b3'],  ['c1','c2','c3'] ]);
```

Outputs:

```
[["a1","b1","c1"],["a2","b2","c2"],["a3","b3","c3"]]
```

---

**UPDATE**:

I found another cleaner implementation of zip as compared to the above. Check it out here: [Javascript equivalent of Python's zip function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856717/javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-zip-function)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to concat the arrays together:

```
var D = A.concat(B, C);
```

Then apply the desired sort:

```
D.sort(function(a, b) {
  return // ...
});
```

If you call `sort()` without arguments, `D` will be alphabetically sorted.

Comment: What about values containing numerical parts > 10?

Comment: I guess `a1`, `a2`, `aN` are dummy values... If there are real values, it's not really complicated to write a sort function.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to concatenate all Arrays, you could write a simple helper function, that makes use of [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
function concatAll () {
  return [].reduce.call (arguments, function (a,b) {return a.concat (b)},[])
}
```

*To use it, simply call it with all arrays you want to concatenate.*

```
var a = ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
    b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
    c = ["c1", "c2", "c3"];

concatAll (a,b,c) //["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"]
```

If you need to sort you array after that too,  [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) takes a function as parameter which you can use to sort after your numerical value first, by putting a weight on it.

```
concatAll (a,b,c).sort(function (a, b) {
    var aVals = a.match(/(\D*)(\d*)/),
        bVals = b.match(/(\D*)(\d*)/),
        weighted = [a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 0, b[1] - a[1]] //[string,number]

    return weighted[0] - 2 * weighted[1] // give the number a double weight

}) //["a1", "b1", "c1", "a2", "b2", "c2", "a3", "b3", "c3"]
```

Heres an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3uSRh/2) on jsFiddle

Comment: @rahul888 For me, it does, did you open your console? Or just paste the above code in your console

Comment: @rahul888 updated the fiddle to instead append the string representation of the array to the body