# Functional assignment with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I tried to generate and array of arrays, beign the inner array elements the tuples from two other arrays.

Like:

```
xArray = [x1,x2,x3,x4...xn]
yArray = [y1,y2,y3,y4...yn]
```

And I need to get a generated array of the from:

```
points = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]...[xn,yn]]
```

I'm a bit aware of python expressions where you can generate an array assigning the values as an expression. **But how could I do this in JavaScript?**

Of course I had to go for a cycle:

```
for (var i = 0;i<xs.length;i++) {

    var pt=[]
    pt.push(xs[i])
    pt.push(ys[i])
    pts.push(pt)
}
```

Comment: This operation is called ["zip"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115563/what-is-zip-functional-programming) and can be found in such libraries as underscorejs. ES6/Harmony will additionally have [generator support](http://domenic.me/2013/09/06/es6-iterators-generators-and-iterables/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var points = [], i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++){
    points.push([xArray[i], yArray[i]]);
}
//points is loaded with your data format.
```

If you were using [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#zip), you could use the following

```
var points = _.zip(xArray, yArray);
```

I recommend lodash, especially if you are going to continue to do a significant data manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to map the arrays into another array. Something like this

```
var points = xArray.map(function(itm, i) {
    return [itm, yArray[i]]; // assuming they have the same length
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mx6Zv/)

This uses `Array.map`, there's a polyfill on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if older browsers is an issue.

Comment: Thanks, aren't functional like statements allowed in JavaScript?