# Powershell functional zip equivalent

Tags: powershell

Is there a PowerShell equivalent to the 'zip' from functional programming?

[What is zip (functional programming?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115563/what-is-zip-functional-programming)

I want to take two input sequences and return a sequence of tuples containing the paired elements.
Is there a built-in method or something built-in to the language that makes this easy?

BTW, I want the solution to be very 'natural' for PowerShell and integrate with the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit cumbersome, but it works:

Script file test.ps1:

```
param( $fnop, $first, $second)

$retval = @()
$len = if($first.length -lt $second.length) { $first.length } else { $second.length }
for( $i = 0; $i -lt $len; $i++) {
    $oprslt = $fnop.invoke( $first[$i], $second[$i])
    $retval = $retval + $oprslt
}

$retval
```

Example:

```
 # add and sort
 PS> .\test.ps1 {param($a,$b) return $a+$b} (3,2,1) (8,-4,5) | sort
 11
 -2
 6

 # add only
 PS> .\test.ps1 {param($a,$b) return $a+$b} (3,2,1) (8,-4,5)
 -2
 6
 11

 # multiply and sort
 PS> .\test.ps1 {param($a,$b) return $a*$b} (3,2,1) (8,-4,5) | sort
 -8
 5
 24
```

The function block `{param($a,$b) return $a+$b}` is your zip function.

Comment: Thanks @JensG, I will study this.  I like the way you passed the function in as the first argument, that makes sense.  Do you think accepting the $first and $second parameter from the pipeline is more "PowerShell"-ish?  I tried writing a version of this that uses the pipeline, but end the end I collected all the pipeline input before working with it, so it is essentially the same as your function.

Comment: Let me put it this way: It does what you wanted. There may be a better or more idiomatic ("powershellish") solution that I'm not aware of right now. So I don't put any guarantees here ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This request has come up from time to time.  The idiomatic PowerShell solution would be a `Join-Object` command.  The PowerShell team wrote this script along with some examples of using it on their blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/07/13/join-object.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point out that you can use tuples natively in Powershell:

```powershell
$q = [System.Tuple]::Create('One','Two')
$q.Item1
$q.Item2
```

This doesn't necessarily help you or even make sense for this situation, but I thought it might interest you.

Comment: the edit is done, previous comment deleted (doesn't make sense any more).