# How to print array data that I just compressed using numpy zip()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, set, zip

I am trying to figure out how to see the the data from the zipped content.
The scenario is as follows in the code:

```
import numpy as np
x=[1,2,3]
y=[4,5,6]
z=[7,8,9]
data=np.array(zip(x,y,z))
print (data)
```

output

```
array(<zip object at 0x00000166568AE648>, dtype=object)
```

but i want to see the data inside the zip so when i say

```
print(data)
```

it shows

```
<zip object at 0x00000166568AE648>
```

---

now people are discussing in similar posts about **D_stacking** like..

```
np.dstack(data)
```

but it shows the output as a error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-2126862e2c70> in <module>()
----> 1 np.dstack(data)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py in dstack(tup)
    407 
    408     """
--> 409     return _nx.concatenate([atleast_3d(_m) for _m in tup], 2)
    410 
    411 def _replace_zero_by_x_arrays(sub_arys):

TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

0 dimension..?
what does this mean..?
it says the same for other possible solution i found as **Decompressing zip**

```
a,b,c=zip(*data)
print('x=',a)
print('y=',b)
print('z=',c)
```

**error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-6ad67a911952> in <module>()
----> 1 a,b,c=zip(*data)
      2 print('x=',a)
      3 print('y=',b)
      4 print('z=',c)

TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

then i went thrugh `zip()` function in programiz.com there i found `set()` function..

```
result = set(data)
print (result)
```

**error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-2e1af52686b4> in <module>()
----> 1 result = set(data)
      2 print (result)

TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

---

i believe I'm doing something bad in basic x,y,z data.. but my knowledge is limited to the level of whatever you think about me..

could you please help me with things I'm missing and also explain that lil important point i missed.

---

When I search for `TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array`

people talk about `json` which I have **0** idea other then FC3, sorry for that.

Comment: The `zip` function in Python has nothing whatsoever to do with compression.

Comment: What were you actually trying to do? Did you *want* to compress something? Why were you calling `zip` at all? What's your desired output?

Comment: You seem to be under the misapprehension that `zip` is compressing your data. It is *not*. It is performing the [functional programming operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115563/what-is-zip-functional-programming) "zip". This takes two sequences and returns a pair of each of their elements at the same position. Like a "zipper". It has nothing to do with the .zip archive file format.

Comment: now that helped me a lot @juanpa.arrivillaga,

Comment: @AhmedAbdulSalam yes, generally, you need to *materialize* the objects into something that numpy will understand, ideally, a sequence of sequences, like a `list` of `lists` if you are passing the `np.array` constructor something. A `zip` object is not something it will understand, and indeed, a `zip` object is potentially an infinite iterator.

Comment: Can you explain me about iteration over a 0 d array..?

Comment: Also in Py3, `zip` returns a `zip object`, not a list.  It's a generator.  `list(zip(...))` is required if you want a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` of a tuple of lists is a kind of list transpose:

```
In [83]: x=[1,2,3]
    ...: y=[4,5,6]
    ...: z=[7,8,9]
    ...: 
In [84]: zip(x,y,z)
Out[84]: <zip at 0xaf79f84c>
```

But in Py3, `zip` is generator like; you have to wrap the result in `list` (or iterate on it) to get a list:

```
In [85]: list(zip(x,y,z))
Out[85]: [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

So far I'm not using `numpy`, just plain Python.  `zip` documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

You can make an array from such a list

```
In [86]: np.array(list(zip(x,y,z)))
Out[86]: 
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Trying to make an array from the `zip` produces a single element array,  0d, that contains a pointer to this `zip object`.  There's little point doing anything more with this.

```
In [87]: np.array(zip(x,y,z))
Out[87]: array(<zip object at 0xaf75d8cc>, dtype=object)
```

---

But to get a 2d matrix from these lists it is easier, or at least more direct, to use some version of `concatenate`, which takes a list of arrays or lists.  `stack` for example lets you specify a new axis to join things:

```
In [88]: np.stack((x,y,z))   # same as np.array((x,y,z))
Out[88]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
In [89]: np.stack((x,y,z),axis=1)
Out[89]: 
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

---

A common use of zip is to iterate on several lists at once:

```
In [92]: for i,j,k in zip(x,y,z):
    ...:     print(i,j,k,i+j+k)
    ...:     
1 4 7 12
2 5 8 15
3 6 9 18
```

---

From the comments you seem to be focused on fetching values from this array:

```
In [97]: data = np.array(zip(x,y,z))
In [98]: data
Out[98]: array(<zip object at 0xabee412c>, dtype=object)
```

You can pull an item out of a 0d array with a `[()]` index.  `data.item()` also works:

```
In [99]: data[()]
Out[99]: <zip at 0xabee412c>
```

Now you can apply list and see the items:

```
In [100]: list(data[()])
Out[100]: [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

`zip` doesn't actually contain its arguments.  Rather it has references to the original lists.  That's true of the `data` arrays as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* to zip the data? You can pass NumPy a list of lists, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
x=[1,2,3]
y=[4,5,6]
z=[7,8,9]
data=np.array([x,y,z])
print (data)
```

output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

Comment: point here is i executed the code

data=np.array(zip(x,y,z))

now i want to see the data that is stored in that 'data'

how can i see..?

Comment: @AhmedAbdulSalam there **is no data stored there**. You've made a `numpy` array with `dtype=object` that contains a `zip` object. That *is the data in the array*.

Comment: you have cleared my confusion by far to a level.. could you please consider giving me a reference link through which i can understand the terms you are talking about..? YT link would be helpful.

Ty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683959/the-zip-function-in-python-3

That may be a helpful intro to zip().

Comment: If only you could guide me.. I only have the above main code.. can u please tell me what knowledge am I supposed to be achieving?  A goal?